# Які труднощі є при переході слов’янських мов з кирилиці на латинку, чи є вони перешкодою для переходу української на латинку?

Tags: абетка, латинка, альтернативні-правописи

Латинка використовується для більшості слов’янських мов, і з цим немає проблем. Відмінність абетки створює додатковий бар’єр поміж нами і західними країнами.

Відразу сам собі заперечу наступним:

1. [Сербохорватська мова](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbo-Croatian) має і латинку, і кирилицю, але і бар’єри нікуди не поділися.
2. Українська кирилиця має всі необхідні літери для передавання звуків, що ними користуються в українській мові, а в латинці доведеться ставити над ними всілякі позначки, як це є у Франції й Німеччині, наприклад.

Заперечення до 2: в Чехії це є, і вони не збираються переходити назад на кирилицю.

Comment: думаю, вас також зацікавить [це](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/Odvertyj_lyst_do_vsix,_xto_cikavyt%27sja_cijeju_spravoju)

Comment: Взагалі, якщо чесно, давно хотів сказати, що це якесь занадто широке (нечітке) запитання і воно, по-моєму, аж надто провокує до висловлення власних суб'єктивних думок. Зокрема: якого саме типу труднощі (соціальні, політичні, технічні, економічні, педагогічні — навіть категорії (потенційних) труднощів можна перераховати безкінечно). Крім того, «чи є вони перешкодою», по-моєму, занадто суб'єктивне (що саме мається на увазі перешкодою: щось нездоланне чи щось, що гальмує процес чи будь-які завади?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Запитання, як на мою думку, занадто широке, але для тих, кому цікаво з якими складнощами вже стикалися при спробах застосувати латинику в українській мові, думаю, будуть корисні наступні відомості:

В вікіпедії є стаття про [українську латинику](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0). В XIX сторіччі було дві великі спроби латинізувати українську абетку, які призвели до так званої [азбучної війни](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0). Обидві спроби мали місце серед української громади австро-угорської імперії.

Перша спроба - [abecadło](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE) при передачі звуків української мови використовує латинику схожу на польську абетку. Яка також іноді називається abecadło, але більш поширена нава [Alfabet](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabet)

Друга спроба - варіант, який запропонував [Josyf Jireček](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84_%D0%87%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA). Ця спроба більше схожа на спробу запозичення тогочасного [чеського алфавіту](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cesk%C3%BD_pravopis)

Азбучна війна закінчилася переходом на переважно кирилічну [драгоманівку](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), в якій, на відміну від сучасної української кирилиці, немає літери `щ`, і звук передається сполученням `шч` (*шчо* є ближчим до принципу 'як чуємо так і пишемо'), й передається як `j`, йотовані голосні передаються як `j + голосна`, пом'якшення приголосних перед голосним як `ь + голосна`.

Також були і пізніші спроби перевести українську на латинику за українських радянських часів "до самогубства [Скрипника](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)":

> 1927 р. під час Всеукраїнської правописної конференції в Харкові мовознавці Майк Йогансен, Борис Ткаченко та Михайло Наконечний запропонували прийняти латинку як частину правопису. Внаслідок голосування переважив один голос проти.
>
> Крім радикального переходу на латинку, існувала ідея впровадження кількох латинських літер — ѕ (замість дз), z (замість дж) та j (замість й, зокрема в є, ї, ю, я). Цю ідею виніс Євген Тимченко, її було частково підтримано і Харківська конференція затвердила введення s та z до української абетки. Проте після того, як ЦК КП(б)У на чолі з Л. Кагановичем засудив впровадження нових літер, конференція анулювала своє рішення

Також, лінгвіст [Юрій Шевельов](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) використовував латинику для передачі сучасної української мови у своїх працях, принаймні написаних англійською та, здається, німецькою мовами. Але при перекладі українською з англійської його "[Історичної фонології української мови](https://books.google.pl/books/about/%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%83.html?id=a33ERmARrc8C&redir_esc=y)" перекладачі [Сергій Вакуленко](http://www.hi-phi.org.ua/index.php/chleny-tovarystva/6-vakulenko-serhii) та [Андрій Даниленко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) використали кирилицю не тільки для передачі ідей українською мовою, а також і приклади, які в оригінальному тексті кодифіковані латиникою.

Також варто не забувати про сучасний і [досить незграбний офіційний варіант](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) латинізації української мови, прийнятий міністерством закордонних справ кабінету [Азарова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).

Answer (score 6):

В Україні питання переходу на латиницю на державному рівні поки що не підіймалось. Не дивлячись на те, що очевидного і простого рішення не існує, ми все таки можемо спробувати проаналізувати це питання з різних сторін.

**З політичної точки зору**

В першу чергу, перехід на латиницю, може сприйматись, в першу чергу, як *політичне* рішення відходу від колоніальної та агресивної політики Російської Федерації щодо колишніх співдружніх республік. Це розуміють і в самій Росії, статті на кшалт ["Гудбай, Russkiy mir"](https://www.novayagazeta.ru/articles/2016/02/22/67521-gudbay-russkiy-mir) без проблем можна знайти після того як влада Казахстану офіційно повідомила про бажання перейти на латиницю до 2025 року:

[image]

Щодо самого Казахстану, то після офіційного повідомлення в країні закономірно [виникли](http://russian.eurasianet.org/node/59994) дискусії:

> Лінгвісти розійшлись в думках з приводу того, що краще - латиниця або
>   кирилиця - передає специфіку звукового ладу казахської мови, і яку
>   форму латиниці слід прийняти (тюркські держави, що використовують
>   латиницю, такі як Туреччина, Узбекистан, Азербайджан і Туркменістан,
>   користуються різними її варіаціями). Існує навіть рух, що виступає за
>   відмову від кирилиці на користь рунічного письма, на якому казахська
>   мову існувала в давнину. У 1929 році в радянському Казахстані
>   казахська мова перевели з арабської в'язі на латиницю, потім в 1940
>   році була введена кирилиця як загальний алфавіт для всіх республік.

Українцям може бути цікавою статистика володіння казахської та російськими мовами в Казахстані, оскільки аргументація, що в країні живе велика кількість виключно російськомовних громадян, є вагомою і для України:

> Надійні статистичні дані про лінгвістичну ситуацію [в Казахстані] знайти непросто,
>   проте згідно з останнім переписом населення від 2009 року лише дві
>   третини громадян республіки повідомили про пристойний знанні ними
>   казахської мови, тоді як 94 відсотки населення заявили, що розуміють
>   російську мову. Астана поставила за мету забезпечити до 2025 року
>   володіння казахською мовою 95 відсотками громадян, зберігши 
>   знання російської на рівні 90 відсотків.

Цікавою є [інформація](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C), що латинським алфавітом (на базі турецького алфавіту) неофіційно користується казахська діаспора в Турції. Також казахська діаспора використовує сурогатні латиниці в Німеччині, США і інших західних країнах.

Ще одним прикладом може бути Білорусь, де за період незалежності кількість людей, що розмовляють білоруською мовою, значно [зменшилась](https://vkurier.by/47398):

> 21 лютого відзначають Міжнародний день рідної мови. Для Білорусі це
>   досить «болюче» свято, адже на рідній для країни мові розмовляють
>   одиниці. Тому стверджувати, що в синьоокою дві державні мови, на жаль,
>   не доводиться: реальність показує зворотне.

Таким чином, з політичної точки щору перехід на латиницю є виправданим.

**З лінгвістичної точки зору**

Не дивлячись на те, що вивчення іноземних мов у нас досить розповсюджене як в школах, так і в вищих навчальних закладах, статистика володіння розмовною мовою та регулярного відвідування іноземних країн в Україні на низькому рівні. З іншої сторони, спроби створення українських аналогів stack overflow, google, facebook та інших популярних зарубіжних ресурсів потерпіли повне фіаско (на відміну від Росії, де популярними якраз є клони популярних сервісів). З цього можна зробити обережний висновок, що для певної кількості українців відсутність української чи російської локалізації не є проблемою з точки зору використання тих чи інших сервісів чи послуг.

З точки зору періодики, книг, навчальних матеріалів, то тут ситуація більш складна, оскільки в більшості випадків цей простір заповнений російськомовним продуктом, а якісних енциклопедій, фундаментальних праць українською надзвичайно мало. Перехід на латиницю, а, як наслідок, збільшення кількості людей, що розуміють іноземні мови, може частково вирішити проблему доступу до знань та матеріалів, що є переважно англійською мовою.

**З практичної точки зору**

Одночасний перехід навряд чи буде можливим, тому компромісним варіатом є існування обох алфавітів та поступовий перехід протягом 10-15 років. На мій погляд, важливим є той факт, який статус у відносинах, насамперед, з Європою буде займати Україна. Якщо євроінтеграційні процеси будуть реальними і будуть реально підтримуватись всіма сторонами, то процес переходу матиме сенс, в іншому випадку залишиться велика кількість людей, що захоче залишити кирилицю в якості запасного варіанту на випадок, якщо євроінтеграційні процеси не будуть фундаментальними та всебічними.

Comment: `як наслідок, збільшення кількості людей, що розуміють іноземні мови` - не зрозуміло, як із використання латиниці витікає збільшення кількості людей, що з латинських літер вміють складати слова іншої мови.

Comment: -1 за "політичну точку зору". Чому б з "політичної точки зору" не зобов'язати використовувати латинику при письмовому спілкуванні російською мовою в Україні?

Comment: @Chizh Чесно говорячи, я не знаю, як можна зобов'язати використовувати латиницю у випадку, коли мова не має латинського варіанту. "Політичною" точку зору я назвав тому, що перехід чи не перехід на латиницю в нашому випадку може залежати не лише від лінгвістичних чи історичних причин, але й враховуючи політику інших країн.

Comment: @sashaeve "Перехід на латинику/арабську/клинопис" з політичної точки зору і є таким примусом. Літературне використання певної системи кодифікації звісно може використовуватися і без 'примусу': вільно і творчо, як наприклад робить [piśmieńnik Uładzimier Arłoŭ](http://www.bramaby.com/ls/blog/bel/2584.html)

Comment: Pro zobragennja: necčodawno Kazakstan troxy [pidpravyw](//zbruc.eu/taxonomy/term/559) latinku.

Answer (score 3):

Можна, наприклад, брати давні відомости, а саме: доволї непогана технічна з 75 сторінками [книга](//diasporiana.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/books/11976/file.pdf) 1933 року „[Йосиф Їречек](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84_%D0%87%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA) і українська мова (до [азбучної заверюхи 1859 р.](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85))“ [Василя Сїмовича](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). Там про мовні і політичні питаня, про сам вплив на мову тошчо. Також проблеми писемностей: як латинкової, так і кириличної.

Також вартий уваги [займавий факт і збіг](https://www.istpravda.com.ua/articles/2021/04/7/159284/):

> … таємний указ імператора Всеросійського Олександра ІІ від 20 жовтня 1859 року про заборону друкування азбук чи інших творів українською мовою з використанням польської абетки.
>
> <sub>У фонді Подільського духовної консисторії Державного архіву Хмельницької області потрапила на очі справа "О запрещении печатания азбук русского языка с применением польского алфавита" (Ф-315, оп. 1, спр. 1484).</sub>

Збіг в тому, же рік той самий, коли Їречек передставив свою латинку. Також можна зауважити, же за 4 роки, а са́ме 1863 року, буде сумнозвісний [Валуєвський циркуляр](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%94%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80).

---

Моя основна думка про перевагу. Українцї ототожнюватимуть себе з латинковим сьвітом, а не з кириличним. Тобто, по-мойому, доречним також варто розглянути питаня трудностїв, коли українська залишається на кирилицї. Один з показових прикладів [сучасности](//theverge.com/2018/5/22/17380630/) про родину кирилицї — Бoлґарія:

> … Twitter announced it would become more aggressive in pursuing trolls on its service, a move which seems to have had some unforeseen consequences, judging by the present upheaval in the Bulgarian Twitter community. An increasingly large and unhappy number of people have had their Twitter accounts suspended and messages filtered out of conversations, apparently for the offense of merely tweeting in Cyrillic. …
>
> ---
>
> … Twitter оголосив, що він стане агресивнішим у переслідувані тролів; цей крок, здається, мав непередбачувані наслідки, судячи з нинішніх потрясінь у болгарській твітер-спільноті. Все більша кількість людей мають заблоковані облікові записи, а їхні повідомленя вилучаються з обговорень — напевно, всього лиш через те, що вони переписувалися кирилицею…
>
> <sub>Дуже приблизний переклад</sub>

Очевидно, шчо таке буває не лиш тут: більшість проґрам спершу нацїлені на латинку, а лиш потім на инші писемности (виняток — власна писемніть, але однаково першою разом чи другою є латинка).

---

Також особисто для себе можете спробувати [переглядацький додаток](//github.com/paiv/latynka), котрий переводить [українську] кирилицю на латинку. Там навіть можна підлаштувати власну спросчену (тому шчо, наприклад з *ў* не працює, тре далї підробити вже джерело) латинку.

---

Про всяк зауважу і доведу деякі хибности твердженя в запитанї і підсилю зауваженя:

> Українська кирилиця має всї необхідні букви для передачи звуків, шчо ними користуються в українській мові, а в латинцї доведеться ставити над ними всілякі позначки, як це є у Франції й Німеччині, наприклад.

**Як є.** Українська кирилиця не має всї необхідні букви для звуків, наприклад: д͡ж, д͡з. Деякі букви позначають декілька звуків чи по-ріжному поводяться. Українська кирилиця теж має розріжняльні чи з’єднувальні знаки, ось найвиразніші: *й*, *ґ*, *щ*, *ї*, *ю*. Очевидно, шчо загальна кирилиця має шче більше таких.

Якшчо було твердженє, шчо сучасна латинка не в змозї замінити сучасну кирилицю без розріжняльних знаків, то це теж не так. Причому без втрати лоґіки з латиною (чи латинописемними мовами) і [африкатів](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82#%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0). Ось [мій] приклад:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A a** | **B b** | [**C c**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C) | **D d** | **E e** | **F f** |
| А а | Б б | Ш ш | Д д | Е е | Ф ф |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| [**G g**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G) | **H h** | **I i** | **J j** | **K k** | **L l** |
| Ж ж | Г г | І і | Й ь | К к | Л л |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **M m** | **N n** | **O o** | **P p** | [**Q q**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%22) | **R r** |
| М м | Н н | О о | П п | Ґ ґ | Р р |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **S s** | **T t** | **U u** | **V v** | **X x** | **Y y** |
| С с | Т т | У у | В в | Х х | И и |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Z z** | ’ |  |  |  |  |
| З з |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **J j** | + | **a** | **u** | **e** | **i** |
|  |  | Я я | Ю ю | Є є | Ї ї |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **T t** | + | **c** | **s** |  | Щ щ |
|  |  | Ч ч | Ц ц |  | Шч шч |
|  |  |  |  |  | Ctc ctc |
| **D d** | + | **g** | **z** |  |  |
| Д д | + | ж | з |  |  |

Також варто зазначити шчодо Нïмецької: замість *ß* чи умляутів (тут складнїше і коли дїйсно немає змоги), то [пишуть](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Standard_German#Written_Swiss_Standard_German) *ss* чи після відповідної голосної [друкують](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography#Umlaut_diacritic_usage) *e*. При потребі, можна розширити правило апострофа, таке слушно і для кирилицї: *від’жити, від’зеркалити, най’обмеженіший*.

*Нагадаю, то лиш приклад на базисї **власного** і чужих досвідів. Мета було просто довести.*

---

Підсиленя до запереченя:

> в Чехії це є, і вони не збираються переходити назад на кирилицю

- Румунська була на [кирилицї](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_language#Writing_system), але за ~60 років від кінця 18 сторічя [перейшла](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE) на латиницю.
- Хорвацька — слов’янська мова і теж [має](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE) деякі розріжняльні знаки. Переходити не збираються, паралельно мали кирилицю (за часи Югославії) і [хорватську глаголицю](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F#%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F) за часи [Усташі](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%96) і для богослужіня до 1960 років.

Очевидно, слов’янських мов більше на латиницї: польська, [білоруська](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0), словацька, словеньська. Країни після-Югославії дають змогу писати двома писемностями, але тут обставини складніші.

---

<sup>Додам до дописів [chizh](/a/230/585) і [sashaeve](/a/225/585)</sup>

> У 1929 році в радянському Казакстані мову перевели з арабської в’язі на латиницю

Цей процес, котрий уявно міг зачепити в подальшому і нас, бо тоді СРСР в 20-30 роках мав [напряму](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%A0%D0%A1%D0%A0) латинизації, деякі кириличні мови теж були переведені, як і були пляни для московської.

---

Окрім латинизації писемности, є шче латинизація самої кирилицї. Дешчо такою думкою підпиралася московська [гражданка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82), як і на *сьогоденя*, як не дивно і знов згадаю, [болґарська](//bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8A%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), або болґариця. Тут малі *к*, *т*, *и* (і похідні *ш*, *ц*…), *д*, *п* підводяться до відповідних латиньських *k*, *m*, *u*, *g* (чи навіть *q*), *n* — дешчо вже вживається наразі, але лише при курсиві. Також помітно деякі огрецькуваня, а отже теж ближче частково до латинки, *в* та *л* до [*ϐ*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_(%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)) (кир. унікод ᲀ) та [*λ*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0). Дивно, шчо таке саме не зробили для великої *Д* до [*Δ*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0_(%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)), хоча подекуди так і [роблять](http://cyreading.blogspot.com/2012/09/blog-post_24.html). Українська новинарня [Збруч](//zbruc.eu/) в меню заміняє *к* на *k*.

Цїкаво, шчо окрім згаданих буков також можна замінити *н* і *з* на *ɴ* і *z* (ꙁ) ( — і все це буде за [старокириличною традицією](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F), це також відкидує плутанини з числом *3*. Варто також згадати про сербську [*ј*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%88_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F)), котра була вживана в украïнському письмі як [драгоманівка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), шчо також є доречнїшим для украïнської, оскільки *й* — *и* з бревісом, шчо тоді означає *коротка и*, хоча насправді тут *коротка і*. Згадана драгоманівка наближує до стилю латинкового письма і відкидує суто кириличні йотовані букви *я*, *ю*, *є* і двозвук *щ* з апострофом, як замінник до твердого знаку; також [розмежить](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk402/TK_wisnyk402_morhun%27uk.htm) *ї* на *йі* та *йи* й унормує написаня йотованих і мʼякшеня.