# Букви Й та Ь — зміна абетки

Tags: абетка, альтернативні-правописи, мʼякий-знак

Зустрів, перепрошую заздалегідь за таке посилання, на російськомовному [Lurkmore](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%81) такий абзац:

> Прихильники оптимізувати абетку, чомусь не вимагають скасувати недвозначно схожі один одного *ь* і *й*, які є похідними від однієї і тій ж самої літери *ь* (яке читалась як *і коротка*), на яких висять одні і ті ж фонеми, що не перетинаються у вживанні. Цілком нескладно звикнути як до *добриь день*, *граь*, *ьод*, так і до *голитисй*, *батйко*, *Нйю-Йорк* і *ллєтйся*. До речі, про цю проблему з дублікатом *короткої і* писали ще в 17 столітті, але ні петровські, ні післяреволюційні реформатори її так і не вирішили.

Дещо схожа ситуація, як на мене, і у нас. Хіба що є «[вйо](http://sum.in.ua/s/v~jo)», але це вигук, причому доволі маловживаний, і зміна на «вьо» буде не дуже чутливим. А про інших не дуже згадую, можливо ви згадаєте. А якщо було б критично, то можна було зробити щось на кшталт «в'ьо» чи «в'йо», тобто за допомогою знака апострофа.

Коли створювалась українська абетка, чи коли Україна стала незалежною, то були якісь свої спроби якось це вирішити, якщо так — чому залишили?

Розумію, що один з сильних мінусів — це звичка, можлива деяка складність у навчання. Але розумне зменшення абетки, то, як на мене, доволі позитивна річ. Один з прикладів: буде ще вільна клавіша (особливо зручно для мобільної) з вільними двома символами, наприклад кома та апостроф. Чи я чогось ще не помічаю?

Comment: У [драгоманівці](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Драгоманівка) взагалі збиралися викинути всі йотовані (*я*, *є*, *ю*, *ї*) і літеру *щ* — відповідно писати *jа/ьа*, *jе/ье*, *jу/ьу*, *jі* (бо *й* там позначалося через *j*) і *шч*. Тоді б цілих п'ять літер звільнилося. Але до об'єднання *й* і *ь* навіть Драгоманов, здається, не дійшов.

Comment: вас також може зацікавити [оце питання](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/221/92)

Comment: @Sasha Дещо чував про це. Зменшення літер спрощує типографію та й дає деякі бонуси, тому я трохи розумію таких прихильників. Тут ще й апостроф знищується чи частково замінюється на j. Але є і інша тут сторона, на відміну того, що в моєму питанні, буде значно збільшуватися кількість букв по ширині, як у польської, де неймовірно багато z та i. Тому я більш розумію супротивників.

Comment: Мені здається, основною перешкодою на шляху об'єднання *й* і *ь* було те, що вони позначають не один звук (/wjɔ/ vs. /wʲɔ/). Новатори готові були відступитися від традицій заради фонетичності (*моја* — драгоманівка, *сьвіт* — желехівка), або, навпаки, готові були частково поступитися фонетичністю заради збереження традиції/зручності — але не готові були відступитися і від того, і від іншого просто заради скорочення кількості літер. Але це лише моя особиста думка.

Comment: @Sasha Доволі цікава думка, ба, можливо, правильною. Але вона трохи дивна, як на мене, бо більшість літер все ж таки можуть мати різні звуки: звична та пом'якшена, твердо йотована чи ні.

Comment: А в чому ціль скорочення кількости букв у абетці? Абетку взагалі  при бажанні можна скоротити на, скажімо, сім букв, _б, д, ґ, з, ж, г, в_ (21,2% абетки), тобто викинувши з неї всі букви, які позначають дзвінку пару до иншої букви, яка позначає глухий. Тоді треба ввести якийсь «дзвінкий знак», скажімо «астерікс», і писати не _любий_, а _люп*ий_, не _знав_, а _с*наф*_, тощо, І до цього теж можна було б звикнути. І такими ж парами можна було б призначити _м–н_ та _л–р_, тоді економія склала б 27,2%, 9 клавіш. Оце я розумію, а ото одну букву викидати, навіщо воно треба? ))

Comment: @YellowSky Як я вже відмітив, зручністю наприклад для клавіатур, типографії, уникнення деякого «дублювання» логіки, тощо. Причому, задля цього мало чого тре: не потрібні якісь додаткові знаки, а апостроф і так відноситься до йотованих. До речі, ось ви смієтесь, але така практика є. Ну, я точно впевнений щодо силабічної абетки [японської](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96). До речі, там чомусь ще не сказано про пів дзвінкості, а там є й таке.

Comment: Щодо "зручності для клавіатур" - така тонка оптимізація навряд чи потрібна. Читав що у Китаї вже готувалися до "оптимізації" ієрогліфів, бо дуже багато символів і важко друкувати. Аж тут почалася комп'ютерізація і потреба в оптимізації зникла. Змінювати правопис, підручники, тощо заради оптимізації однієї літери - буде більше витрат ніж економії.

Comment: Будь ласка, уточніть ваше запитання. Бо якщо воно, дійсно, запитує, **«Коли створювалась українська абетка, чи коли Україна стала незалежною, то були якісь свої спроби якось це вирішити, якщо так — чому залишили?»**, то обидві наявні відповіді не відповідають на запитання стосовно «спроб якось це вирішити», а значить, і неможливо відповісти, «чому залишили».

Comment: @bytebuster, формально Ви праві — формально текст каже відповідати на запитання «чому залишили?» лише в тому випадку якщо «[у XIX–XX] були спроби». Але ми ж не роботи, ми розуміємо, що реально автора цікавить відповідь на «чому залишили?» навіть якщо спроб і не було (в такому випадку «чому їх не було?» і т.д.). Та й хай сам автор вирішує.

Comment: @Sasha, *(тут я вдягаю шапку «злого поліцейського»)* є багато інших місць, де на запитання відповідати не обов'язково. Чатіки, комуни на блоґ-платформах, численні пабліки у соцмережах тощо. Наш сайт, натомість, люблять за те, що у нас тут не abstract chit-chatting на вільну тему, а сайт запитань-і-відповідей. І тому варто таки дотримуватися рамок формату. А якщо слідувати вашій логіці, то у відповідях під цим запитанням можна писати усі свої думки стосовно (неосяжної) теми про можливу реформу правопису. Але ж це не так.

Comment: @bytebuster, мені здається, Ви надто буквально читаєте питання. Більшість людей, мабуть, прочитають «… спроби якось це вирішити, *якщо так —* чому залишили» як «… спроби якось це вирішити *і* чому залишили». (Якщо автор спеціально не акцентуватиме на цьому увагу — а він не акцентує.)

Comment: Що ж, пан модератор, скоріш за все, має рацію. Відповіді не дуже влучні щодо мого контексту.

Comment: _Продовження, бо я не встиг відредагувати._ Відповіді не дуже влучні щодо мого контексту, чи моє питання не таке. Я просто оглянув старі проекти 33 років (в тому числі «драгоманівка», що вказували тут) та проект 99 (що є, по суті, розгляд та урегулювання 33 років чи щось того) за часів вільної України. І я отримав значну частину відповідей: ця тема не дуже і розглядалась (окрім деяких моментів апострофів чи урегулювання йотованих літер) — це було б краще це підмітити в відповідях, хоча би для інших (я тут проґавив). А на останнє питань відповіли, де я і як я проґавив у план вирішень проблем.

Comment: @Follower, тоді пропоную вже залишити так, як є, бо і accepted answer вже з'явився. Але якщо у вас виникне бажання *суттєво* переробити запитання, то ніщо вас не обмежує переформулювати і запитати знову. Головне — щоб друге запитання не дублювало те, яке вже є. Окрім того, у нас вже було [англомовне запитання](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/164/) на цю ж тему, але про звуки, а не про абетку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Викладене нижче — це винятково моя особиста думка. Але саме питання, по-моєму, філософське і запитує про особисті міркування.

#### Ми стоїмо далі за росіян від такої реформи, бо в нас немає літери «ё».

Справді, дивно буде писати слова, [зазначені Kyrylo Yatsenko](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1099/4), як «зʼйомка», «серʼйозний», «Воробʼйов» (вставляючи апостроф, щоби *ь/й* після Вашої реформи не пом'якшувало попередній приголосний), а *бульйон*, *каньйон*, *лосьйон* — як «булйʼйон», «канйʼйон», «лосйʼйон» (чи «булййон», «канййон», «лосййон»?).

Логічніше вже ввести літеру *ө* (я спеціально не запозичую російську *ё* (або, наприклад, *є̈*), щоби з нею випадково не запозичити недбалість її вживання) і писати «зʼөмка», «серʼөзний», «Воробʼөв» — відповідно, після Вашої реформи «бульөн», «каньөн», «лосьөн» зіллються з «булйөн», «канйөн», «лосйөн».

#### А чи не заважає росіянам відсутність літери «ї» провести цю реформу?

<sub>Це могло би здаватися логічним: у нас в ряду йотованих бракує *ө*, і це заважає нам провести таку реформу — але ж у них в ряду йотованих не вистачає *ї*.</sub>

Ні, не заважає; навпаки, фактично допомагає, вирішуючи іншу проблему.

Адже традиційно росіяни позначають сполуку звуків [йі] таким чином — *ьи* (при тому, що російська *и* не вважається йотованою: [1](http://www.logozavr.ru/1554/), [2](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/543/)): *воробьи* [воробйі], *соловьи* [соловйі] тощо (я в дитинстві довго не міг повірити, що воно справді так пишеться). Тобто росіяни *вже* частково змішують *ь* і *й* — залишилося змішати остаточно.

Comment: Нічого собі, вельми влучно й цікаво. У словах з «префіксом» і йотованими я — _без'язикий, від'їзд, з'єднаний, з'їхати, з'явитися, об'єм, під'їхати, роз'юшити, роз'яснити_ вже використовується подібна схема. І як буде потрібна буква «ьо» для більш естетичного вигляду. А як саме, це вже інше питання. Хоча, я би якось так уніфікував, наприклад з макроном зверху: м'а̄ч, е̄вроремонт, биӣ, īжак, бульо̄н, ӯката. А щодо російської «ї», цікавий момент, я його не помічав. До речі, можна сюди також підключити систему лігатурів, наприклад автоматична заміна йо = о̄ при написанні.

Comment: @Follower, так, якби ще й уніфікувати (*я* → *а̄*, *є* → *е̄*, *ї* → *і̄*, *ьо/йо* → *о̄*, *ю* → *ӯ*) — взагалі прикольно було б. До речі, у Вас у коментарі одрук — мало б бути «було̄н», а не «бульо̄н» (update: а, ні, нема одруку, це я вже туплю).

Answer (score 6):

Слова, в яких "й" іде після приголосної: "підйом", "зйомка", "серйозний", "курйоз", "шевйот" і похідні.
Також будуть проблеми з прізвищами на кшалт "Воробйов".

Так, ці проблеми можна розв'язати апострофом. Але головна проблема (моя суб'єктивна точка зору) в тому, що написання впливає на вимову. Ми можемо згадати історію з г/ґ. Хоча за радянських часів ніхто не сперечався, що "грунт" треба вимовляти "ґрунт", але про це майже забули лише за 60 років! Така зміна цілком може призвести до зміни звучання обох літер (й,ь) до якогось середнього (хоч я й не можу уявити, що це буде).

Якщо вже дійсно мінімізувати кількість літер в абетці, то тут є багато опцій без жодних змістовних втрат, як зазначали в коментарях:

1. Літера "щ" завжди позначає "шч". Така зміна ще й сприятиме правильній вимові, бо багато хто вимовляє "шьо", якщо більш знайомий з російською мовою. Виграємо одну літеру без жодних втрат.
2. Літери "я", "ю", "є", "ї" можна замінити на йа/ьа, йу/ьу, йе,ье, йі. Виграємо 4 літери + апостроф стає непотрібним. Тут найбільша проблема в теплих почуттях до рідних літер "є" та "ї" ). Також, згідно зі швидким власним дослідженням текст у середньому збільшиться приблизно на 7.5% від таких змін.

Якщо у вас дійсно є бажання змінити абетку, то рекомендую приєднатися до одного з вищенаведених рухів: є чимало прибічників цих змін, дехто навіть пише всі повідомлення так.

Також є рух за додавання декількох літер до української абетки џ (дж) та ѕ (дз, це не латинська s).

Comment: «Можемо згадати історію з г/ґ» — або з «ї/і» (в значенні варіантів «і»). «Може призвести до зміни звучання обох літер (й,ь) до якогось середнього» — причому навіть свого в кожному регіоні.

Comment: Що я би, можливо, зробив — це викинув «ї». Щоби «і» на початку слова і після голосних читалося як [йі]. А в тих місцях, де на початку слова потрібна саме [і], писав би «и»: «инший» (щоби воно варіативно могло читатися як [и] чи [і] чи проміжне). Але це суперечить навіть проекту-99 (навіть там частина слів залишалася з «і» на початку слова: «існує».)

Comment: Хм, з «правила чітко предписують, що перед йотованою після бпвмфр може бути лише апостроф, а після дтзсцлн — лише м'який знак» я помилився. Прибираю той коментар.